# Is Apache wildcard Include directive recursive?

Tags: apache, directive

According to Apache manual, the Include directive is recursive when a directory path is used. But is it recursive when using a wildcard path?

```
 Include "/usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/username/domain.com/*.conf"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Joyce already said, I can confirm by testing it myself that it is not recursive.
`Include` uses `fnmatch` as wildcard engine, which doesn't match a slash by default, unless the `FNM_PATHNAME` flag is set, so a `*` doesn't match `/` so `domain.com/*.conf` will not look in sub-directories.

However, since [httpd 2.3.6](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#include) it is possible to also use the wildcard for sub-directories.

#### Examples

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d/ssl.conf
```

This matches only a specific file.

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d
```

If `conf.d` is a file, it matches only this file. If `conf.d` is a directory, all files will be matched recursively, including files in sub-directories and non-conf files (which causes an error).

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d/*.conf
```

This will only match the files with a `.conf` suffix, directly located in the `conf.d` directory. Files in sub-directories aren't matches.

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d/*/*.conf
```

This will only match the files with a `.conf` suffix, directly located in sub-directories of the `conf.d` directory, but it will NOT match files directly located in the `conf.d` directory.

So for example, if you need to match all `.conf` files directly located in  `conf.d` and in first level of sub-directories and second level of sub-directories, you can use this:

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d/*.conf
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d/*/*.conf
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d/*/*/*.conf
```

If you only have valid configuration files in `conf.d` and want to match every level of subdirectories, then you can use:

```
Include /usr/local/apache2/conf.d
```

Answer (score 3):

I checked it and it is not recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using wildcard, you should use a directory.

It has been supported since as early as 1.3 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#include

> New in Apache 1.3.13 is the feature that if Include points to a directory, rather than a file, Apache will read all files in that directory, and any subdirectory, and parse those as configuration files.